# Handling a touch event across multiple subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am new to iOS development. I have a custom drawn view which is composed of multiple subviews covering the target area on screen. Specifically this is a board game like chess where I used a view for each square. The squares are created as subviews on a UIView. There is one UIViewController for this. From what I read, I have to have touchesBegan, touchesEnded etc calls in my UIView to handle these. But none of these functions are getting called. I added these calls on the base view and all the subviews. So -

1. How do I simulate these touch events in the iOS simulator? A mouse click is not calling the touchesBegan ,touchesEnded calls on any view.
2. Ideally I would like to handle these in the UIViewController because I want to run the touch through some logic. Is that possible? How do I achieve it?

Comment: Are you setting up your touch events in IB/Storyboard or in code? If in code, can you show how they're being added?

Comment: @Stonz2 - I found the problem, I had to enable the user interaction on the view. I was setting it up programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when I add the view programmatically and not through the storyboard the userInteractionEnabled variable is set to NO by default. After setting it up, I get the touchesEnabled call getting called in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)
It is tutorial in Apple sample codes it describes how to handle touches very nicely.
Just run the sample code and go through description you will get clear idea how touches work un iOS.

Comment: I found the problem. Please see my answer above. Your link to the sample could be useful to me. I will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(![touch.view isKindOfClass:[yourView class]])
    {
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.